# phonegap + phonejs style challenges

Tags: css, cordova, phonejs

I'm starting to use phonegap and phonejs to write mobile hybrid applications. I've followed the tutorial http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Getting_Started/Your_First_Application and the app works but both on the emulator and on the device the widgets are *extremely* small (see screenshot https://db.tt/ZhdrOt0R, sorry for the volume dialog on the screenshot). Like this, the app is completely unusable. I checked the various css files for font-size and other size tags but there are so bloody many places...
This leads me to a more generic question: I'd like buttons with rounded corners, different margins etc. What's the strategy to change the style? There are so many classes, is there any how to how to address this other than in a trial-and-error fashion?

Thx
Kai

Comment: Look for `media queries` and `viewport` in the internet. They can help you to deal with CSS and screen compatibility issues.

Comment: The phonejs stylesheets should already be optimized for mobile devices. I'm more or less looking for a phonejs specific guide how to adapt the appearance to custom needs.

Comment: Found it! <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1"/> and everything appears bigger. I'll continue searching for which css classes I need to modify in order to modify appearance of buttons, etc.